# Latex - figures side by side using loop

Tags: floats, loops

I am trying to put 6 figures in 3rows & 2 columns:

```
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
{
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{This is the caption.}
\vspace{0.0cm} \centering
\includegraphics[height = 5.4cm]{figures/fig\x.eps}
\end{figure}
}
```

I want only one caption in first figure page and same figure number for next 6 figures in next page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the `pgffor` (or `tikz`) package, a pair of cycles (inner and outer) and several conditions to polish the result. In a real project I would use the `subfigure` package and two independent pages to get cross-references clickable to both parts.

I enclose an example and a preview of pages. Those 12 pictures (`fig*`) must be stored in the `figures/` folder to successfully compile the code.

```
%! *latex morepics.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}% or tikz
\usepackage{mwe}
%\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,2} {%
\ifnum\x=2\addtocounter{figure}{-1}\fi
\newpage
\begin{figure}%[!ht]
\centering
\caption{This is the caption.}%
\foreach \y in {1,...,6}{%
  \pgfmathparse{int((\x-1)*6+\y)}
  % We need figures/fig1 to figures/fig12 to be able to compile this particular example.
  \includegraphics[height=6.5cm]{figures/fig\pgfmathresult} 
  \ifnum\y=2\par\fi
  \ifnum\y=4\par\fi
  }% End of the inner \foreach...
\end{figure}%
}% End of the outer \foreach...
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

**Edit:** changes in packages: +`mwe`, -`subfigure`, -`tikz`, +`pgffor`. Instead of using figures 1-6 and using them twice, it is now loading figures 1 to 12.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `subfigure` from the `subcaption` package? Putting each `subfigure` to `.48\textwidth` or sth would be easier, i think.

Comment: Consider to load `pgffor` rather than the heavy `tikz`; moreover, I think you're missing a call to `mwe`.

Comment: Thank you for an advice! To the `mwe` package, it might be a problem, yes, I am using only one picture which is stored and findable in the TeX structure (TeX Live), but it could be a problem with other TeX distributions (untested).

Comment: @Malipivo: I was mentioning `mwe` because your example, as it is, it is not compilable. Adding `mwe` to the list of loaded packages makes your mwe compilable. Please, note that for the purpose of answering, it is completely fine to use that package even if others can not compile. You can highlight that the package is used for demonstration purposes only: others have to replace with actual pictures. What I usually do is: `\usepackage{mwe} % for dummy images`.

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino Thank you, I have modified the code. It was running at my computer, but thank you for letting me know! I will pay attention to this particular problem in my next posts.

Comment: @Malipivo Thanks for a very nice reply. I replaced {example-image-10x16} with {figures/fig\y.eps}. And it works nicely for the first six figures (fig1...fig6). However, in the next page, instead of taking fig7...fig12, it repeats the same six figures - fig1...fig6. If this get fixed this will solve my problem.

Comment: when I am replacing 1,...,6 by 1,...,12 it tries to put all the 12 figures in a single page.

Comment: @raj You are welcome! I have submitted a new version, please try it if it fits your needs.